# Does divide-and-conquer exploit optimal substructure?

Tags: divide-and-conquer

In the divide-and-conquer approach, subproblems are independent of each other. 
Thus, overlapping subproblems cannot be exploited.

The CLRS definition of optimal substructure states: 
"a problem exhibits optimal substructure if an optimal solution to the problem contains within it optimal solutions to subproblems."
Do we know that solutions to subproblems using the divide-and-conquer approach are optimal? If so, I gather that optimal substructure applies for the divide-and-conquer approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is very quick to prove to yourself.

Given an algorithm with a divide and conquer solution, suppose it does not have an optimal substructure. I will make up some simple notation: P is the overall problem, PL and PR are the left and right subproblems. S(P) is the solution to P.

By the definition of a divide and conquer solution, it is required that S(P) = S(PL) + S(PR), where + is the recombination of subproblems solutions.

By the definition of a problem known to not have optimal substructure, it is not necessarily the case that S(P) = S(PL) + S(PR).

This is an immediate contradiction from the definitions. The assumption contradicts the given, so the assumption must be false.

You can switch the given and the assumption to get the same contradiction.

So saying that a problem has an optimal substructure is equivalent to saying that problem has a divide and conquer solution.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?